# Почему баннер добавляется только к одной карточке?

Tags: javascript

Нужно определённым карточкам добавлять баннер.
`case` работает верно для обеих карточек (в консоли выводится оба имени), но баннер ставится только на последнюю. Пробовал отдельными блоками через `if`, но результат тот же.

```
function setCardBanner() {
  const cardArt = document.querySelectorAll('.goodsart')
  const cardImg = document.querySelectorAll('.imgsize-catalog')
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  const span = document.createElement('span')

  div.classList.add('coauthor')
  span.textContent = 'Соавтор курса'

  for (let i = 0; i < cardArt.length; i++) {
    const author = cardArt[i].textContent

    switch (author) {
      case 'Фарида Рубин':
      case 'Наталья Фебер':
        console.log(author)
        cardImg[i].classList.add('rel')
        cardImg[i].appendChild(div).appendChild(span)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Потому что один div может существовать только в одном месте. Создавайте новые в цикле.

Comment: А как-то через cloneNode можно это делать? Я просто не понимаю, как это реализовать.

Comment: Можно. Неважно как, главное что бы это был новый элемент.

Comment: Пробовал разные методы - insertBefore, prepend, но все они добавляют "детей" только в последнюю карточку и удаляют из предыдущей. В отладчике я это чётко увидел, что баннер сначала устанавливается на первую карточку из "кейса", а потом перепрыгивает на вторую. Какой метод использовать, чтобы он именно вставлял в ноду без переноса "детей". Вообще не понимаю, как это происходит, ведь в следующей итерации я работаю уже с другим значением массива.

Comment: Вставьте эти строки в цикл:

const div = document.createElement('div')
const span = document.createElement('span')

-------------------------
вы должны каждый раз создавать новый элемент div и span

Выше вам указали - что вы создали только один div, поэтому вы и видите только один div

Comment: Спасибо! Прочитал много статей по этому вопросу и до меня наконец дошло, что я работаю по сути с адресами, а не со строками. Для новичка порой трудно это осознать, но всё же удалось с этим разобраться, как раз в тот же момент, когда Вы ответили. Благодаря экспериментам, удалось построить верную логику и понять как это устроено.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setCardBanner() {
  const cardArt = document.querySelectorAll('.goodsart')
  const cardImg = document.querySelectorAll('.imgsize-catalog')

  for (let i = 0; i < cardArt.length; i++) {
    const author = cardArt[i].textContent

    switch (author) {
      case 'Фарида Рубин':
        console.log(author)

        const div1 = document.createElement('div')
        const span1 = document.createElement('span')

        div1.classList.add('coauthor')
        span1.textContent = 'Соавтор курса'
        div1.prepend(span1)
        cardImg[i].prepend(div1)
        cardImg[i].classList.add('rel')
        break
      case 'Наталья Фебер':
        console.log(author)

        const div2 = document.createElement('div')
        const span2 = document.createElement('span')

        div2.classList.add('author')
        span2.textContent = 'Автор курса'
        div2.prepend(span2)
        cardImg[i].prepend(div2)
        cardImg[i].classList.add('rel')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]